# Getting an object's fieldsets returns lowercased API names

Tags: apex, rest-api, fieldsets

```
Map<String, Schema.fieldset> fieldMap = Schema.SObjectType.Object_Name.fieldSets.getMap();
```

this properly returns a map of the fieldsets paired with their API names but the names come in all lowercase - everything else maintains its casing.

Is this default behavior and, if so, is there a workaround to get the proper casing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is the default behavior, and no there's no "direct" workaround. The reason why is because the Map returned by the call is actually a special map that I'll call CaseInsensitiveKeyMap. A normal map would more appropriately be called a CaseSensitiveKeyMap, because "Hello" and "hello" are two unique keys (because they use hashCode(), which will definitely return unique values for even a change in string case).

On the other hand, the describe calls, such as `fields.getMap()` and `fieldSets.getMap()`, effectively call `String.toLowerCase()` on each key before calling `hashCode()`, such that you can ask for `Name`, `NAME`, or `name` (or any other permutation) to get the correct field. Field names are case insensitive in Apex Code, and this map mimics that behavior.

If you absolutely wanted to have a case sensitive map, you'd have to construct your own Map, iterate through the values from the describe call, and set each key individually. This would be a large waste of CPU time for no real benefit, since there shouldn't be any specific reason why you need to have the correct casing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is the default behavior.

I usually loop on keyset and get description of the field with [getDescribe](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_class_Schema_SObjectField.htm)

```
Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> fieldsMap = objectDescribe.fields.getMap(); 
for(SObjectField field:fieldsMap.values()){
    String name = field.getDescribe().getName();
 }
```

Comment: You could just iterate through values() instead, though; this is faster since you won't have to retrieve the values from the map.

Comment: improved @sfdcfox